# CUSPARSE_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR with cuSparse cusparseSnnz function

Tags: cuda, sparse-matrix

I am trying to get familiar to the cuSparse library. In my simple code, the function *cusparseSnnz* returns the status 6 which is CUSPARSE_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR. I think the CUDA driver and cuSparse library are correctly installed. I would be really appreciated if someone could help me. Thanks.

```
cusparseStatus_t status;
cusparseHandle_t handle=0;
cusparseMatDescr_t descr=0;

status = cusparseCreate(&handle);
if (status != CUSPARSE_STATUS_SUCCESS) {
    cout << "CUSPARSE Library initialization failed" << endl;
}
status = cusparseCreateMatDescr(&descr);
if (status != CUSPARSE_STATUS_SUCCESS) {
    cout << "Matrix descriptor initialization failed" << endl;
}
status = cusparseSetMatType(descr, CUSPARSE_MATRIX_TYPE_GENERAL);
if (status != CUSPARSE_STATUS_SUCCESS) {
    cout << "cusparseSetMatType failed" << endl;
}
status = cusparseSetMatIndexBase(descr, CUSPARSE_INDEX_BASE_ZERO);
if (status != CUSPARSE_STATUS_SUCCESS) {
    cout << "cusparseSetMatIndexBase failed" << endl;
}
int nnzPerRow[2];
int nnzTotal;
float tempf[6];
tempf[0] = 1.0;
tempf[1] = 0.0;
tempf[2] = 3.4;
tempf[3] = 0.0;
tempf[4] = 2.2;
tempf[5] = 8.6;
float* d_Temp;
cudaMalloc((void**)&d_Temp, sizeof(float)*6);
cudaMemcpy(d_Temp, tempf, sizeof(float)*6, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
status = cusparseSnnz(handle, CUSPARSE_DIRECTION_ROW, 2, 3, descr, d_Temp, 2, nnzPerRow, &nnzTotal);
if (status != CUSPARSE_STATUS_SUCCESS) {
    cout << "nnz calculation failed" << endl;
    cout << "status = " << status << endl;
}
cout << "nnzPerRow[0] = " << nnzPerRow[0] << endl;
cout << "nnzPerRow[1] = " << nnzPerRow[1] << endl;
```

Answer (score 4):

I just found what was wrong. nnzPerRow needs to be located in the device.

```
int nnzPerRow[2];
```

This should be as follows:

```
int* nnzPerRow=0;
checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void**)&nnzPerRow, sizeof(int)*2));
```